# Are there any character detection packages for Python?

Tags: python, image, ocr, libraries

Are there any character detection packages for Python?

I'm not actually interested in what the character is, only that there is a character in the image. Specifically, I'm writing a program that kind of zooms in on each individual character and then does the [OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition).

Our general idea is to find each character, and then do an [image Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_analysis#Applications_in_signal_processing) on the character in the image and compare that to a library of character fouriers. Let me know if I should be more specific. We really are trying to find a way to efficiently identify which mini-images to do the Fourier transform for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PyTesser](http://code.google.com/p/pytesser/) is a Python binding to Google's [Tesseract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract_%28software%29) engine for OCR.